# Filling the area between two circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I fill the area between two concentric circles (or even slightly eccentric) using only tikz (preferably without pgfplots)? I have found many sort-of similar questions, but nothing that quite addresses this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) circle (1);
    \draw (0, 0) circle (1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to fill the area between these two with the color gray. I would prefer *not* to fill the inner circle with white color, but leave that transparent, or unfilled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `even odd rule` for filling. The red line is just to show the inner circle is transparent.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red,thick] (-1.2,-1.2) -- (1.2,1.2);
  \fill[gray!40,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (1.2) (0,0) circle (1);
  \draw (0, 0) circle (1);
  \draw (0, 0) circle (1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solved it.

Comment: It is possible to simplify by using `\filldraw`, like this: `\filldraw[fill=gray!40,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (1.2) (0,0) circle (1);` Then it's not necessary to redraw the outline on top of the filled part.

Comment: @DNF Yes, or `\draw[fill=gray!40,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (1.2) (0,0) circle (1);`.

Answer (score 5):

I can't resist to showing how simple it is with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border = 5ptt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% to compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeXLive, MacTeX)

 \begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\psRing[linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=Salmon, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=WhiteSmoke](0,0){1}{1.2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what use you want to do of this shape, but if it fits your needs, you can also use the `double` line provided by Tikz.

I also used a red line to show that the middle is still empty.

### Output (slightly zoomed in)

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[red] (-1.2,-1.2) -- (1.2,1.2);

\draw[double=gray, double distance=2mm] (0,0) circle (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this with MetaPost, which may be of some use for `tikz` users since MetaPost inspired `tikz` for some concepts (e.g, paths): connecting one of the circle to the other (reversed) with the `--` operator (same syntax as in `tikz`), and then close the resulting ring (`-- cycle` instruction).

This way this ring can be filled, without unfilling the inner circle (i.e.  without filling it with the background color, in this case white).

I have included the MetaPost code into a LuaLaTeX program for convenience.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
path circle[], ring;
circle1 = fullcircle scaled 4cm;
circle2 = fullcircle scaled 3cm;
ring = circle1 -- reverse circle2 -- cycle;
beginfig(1);
    fill ring withcolor .7white;
    draw circle1; draw circle2;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]