# How to unfill an area inside a filled one in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, fillbetween

I've searched a bit and tried in different ways but I don't manage to get the area of the inside circle unfilled, or, alternatively, to be able to fill only the area between the two circles.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm, gray, very thin] (-3.5,-2.5) grid (3.5,2.5);
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\path[fill=gray, opacity=0.2] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is what it plots:
[image]

Edit:

I've found an answer here: [Filling the area between two circles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412597/filling-the-area-between-two-circles) still want to know if it is possible to unfill a previously filled area though.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The short answer is no, you cannot "unfill" an area.  You can fill on top of it, but hidden background objects will stay hidden.  You can, however, not fill part of a filled area in the first place.

Comment: If your question is how not to fill the circle in the middle, then you may just be looking for `even odd rule`: `\path[fill=gray, opacity=0.2,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (2cm) circle (1cm);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are only looking for `even odd rule`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm, gray, very thin] (-3.5,-2.5) grid (3.5,2.5);
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\path[fill=gray, opacity=0.2,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (2cm) circle (1cm);
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The closest thing to "unfilling" that comes to my mind is do all the fills on the background layer. Then the effect may (or may not, depending on whom you ask;-) be described as "unfilling".

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,1}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm, gray, very thin] (-3.5,-2.5) grid (3.5,2.5);
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\ifnum\X=0
\node[anchor=south,font=\sffamily] at (0,2) {fill};
\else
\node[anchor=south,font=\sffamily] at (0,2) {``unfill''};
\fi
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path[fill=gray, opacity=0.2] (0,0) circle (2cm) circle (1cm);
\ifnum\X=0
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\else
\draw[dashed,fill=white] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fi
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've previously edited the question to clarify that I'm looking for a method different from the even or odd one but as John Kormylo said in his comment maybe it is impossible to do

Comment: @EdoardoSerra I added a second possibility which may come close to "unfilling".